# Unable to access the PHP myadmin in windows due to the new security feature of xamp

Tags: windows-7, xampp, phpmyadmin

Mine is a windows 7 64 bit machine with xamp v1.8.0,drupal 7.34 installed on the local server.
I connect to the sever using the mstsc run command and load the url of the PHP myadmin and it loads perfectly whereas when I open the same using the IPaddress:port no/php myadmin on the machine I get the access forbidden .
[image: New security feature of xamp .Access to the requested object is only available from the local network.This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf"]

I don't understand what is this new feature due to which it is restricting access
I have searched the file named xamp.conf but dont get what to change.

Comment: If you read it says you can change that by changing the configuration file. There'll be a setting that you'll find is set to only localhost. It'll get you to change it to, I believe, 0.0.0.0 so it can listen on all interfaces.